# Color change of an icon in <EditText>

Tags: android, xml

Does anyone know how I can change a color of an icon (`svg` done with the help of `-vector-`) that I have implemented in my `EditText`.

Implementation by: `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24px"  ?? :s`
P.s 
color of the icon and input text should not be the same in my application

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:drawableTint="@color/color"` to change the  icon color.
where color means the color defined in the colors.xml located in the values folder
res/values/colors.xml to be precise. It has all the xml tags for colors. For Example: #FF4081 .SO in this case it will change to android:drawableTint="@color/colorAccent" ..Hope you got this :)

Comment: drawableTine is only used in API 23+

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround like:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/back_action_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/components_title_left_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/components_title_top_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backImageIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left_bold_circle_outline_white_36dp"
        android:tint="@color/package_components_title_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textForPackageTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"       
        android:textColor="@color/package_components_title_color"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="@dimen/page_title_size" />

    </LinearLayout>
```